# Creating a link between an Excel spreadsheet and a list

Tags: list, excel, links-list

I have a query regarding something I’m not sure is possible. Hopefully somebody can tell me whether that is the case or not.

We have an Excel document that we issue to suppliers after an audit, outlining the findings raised on each line. Each line has the following columns:
•   Finding number
•   Finding description
•   Finding raised date
•   Corrective action (supplier completes this)
•   Corrective action planned completion date (supplier completes this)

Is it possible to have that Excel spreadsheet linked to a list in SharePoint? So for example once that sheet is completed (or half completed) and stored in a document library another list library can extract the pertinent information and store it in a list? This list would then consolidate all the individual spreadsheets into a reportable format once they had been uploaded?

I’m struggling to get the link between a spreadsheet and a list? Not sure it is possible?

Using SP2013

Thanks

Comment: with coding, yes, are you able to code something?

Comment: I can to some extent, but I am not a programmer by trade so it isn't my forte exactly. How would it work using code in principle?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to access the files in a document library via C# SharePoint Library and read from an excel file.

Read from excel file:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380/reading-excel-from-c?forum=vsto

Use C# to access sharepoint list:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx

Then you could make an event receiver for your document library, then open the excel-file once it's uploaded and store the information in your sharepoint list.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at that. Is there anyway to update an existing list item from an excel spreadsheet? For example if I use one of the columns in excel as the primary key/ID for the list item in sharepoint? Having looked through the methods for SPListItem I can't seem to see anything that for updating? Just adding and deleting as you already mentioned.

Comment: you edit a list item when you write Item["Fieldname"] = newValue; and then call Item.Update(); and yes there is an internal id for list items but you could make one yourself and add a column to your list for that where you store our primary IDs from the excel file, then you could ask for that field via Item["ID"] = id;